# C# Mono IDE architecture in mac

Tags: c#, mono

How c# written code is running on mac version of Mono. Can you please explain because as far as i know Mac doesn't support .exe files. Then when we build a c# application how it run on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It's a massive topic.  But to address the .exe file point, you would launch mono with the .exe as the parameter of the mono process. It's not the native OS that is 'supporting' the .exe, it is mono itself.

This is really no different to any .net implementation, in that the 'executable' runs in a sandbox, not directly interfacing with the OS.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the quick reply. But i am wondering how a program(C# .Net) simple console application .exe(IL) build on window system doesn't run on Mac. If Mono has implemented .Net Framework then it should able to run this .exe anyway because after all this is just a Intermediate Language(MSIL) file and not a native file so as per my understanding it should run. Can you please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks you.

Comment: Are you running it in Mono? You can't just try to launch the exe.  If you run an .exe in Mono and it tries to access some sort of system resource, or assembly that Mono doesn't support you should get an error message.  What kind of error are you getting?  I'm not particularly familiar with using Mono on a Mac, but in principle what you are asking is possible, it comes down to the specifics of the errors you are getting.  Possibly something the console app is trying to do that is not supported by the Mono implementation on the Mac (e.g. access Windows specific features).

Comment: @Jnana IF the exe is mono compatable (eg doesnt p/invoke windows api) it should run. What errors do you get in terminal with: mono yourapp.exe command?

Comment: @user574632 and James Gaunt Thanks for responding.i think i have not represented it properly my apology. I copied the .exe(console app build in .Net framework)from window and running it in Mac which for obvious reason it didn't run. Now my question is if i create a simple HelloWorld console app in c#.net using Mono's Xmarine IDE in Mac and run the app then how and which file it run's and show me the output. I have seen it creating the .exe. How can it run .exe in Mac ???? Thanks

Comment: You launch the Mono runtime, passing the path of the exe as a parameter. You'll obviously need Mono installed on the Mac. Simple example is shown on the project homepage: http://mono-project.com/Mono:OSX, the point is that Mono is the thing you launch, the .exe is a parameter, same as opening a .jpg in GIMP for example. You can't run .net apps on a Mac without the Mono .net framework installed, same as you can't run them on the PC without .net installed, it's not something any OS supports natively.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Thanks for replying, what i understood from your reply is that if i run HelloWorld.exe(Console C# .Net App) on window OS with .Net framework installed and on Mac with Mono .net framework installed both are same right?? If so than how the same .exe runs on Window OS directly and doesn't run directly on Mac is my doubt :) Thanks

Comment: It doesn't run on Windows OS directly, it runs on the .net framework in both cases. There is some bootstrap code within the .exe which launches .net when it is executed directly within Windows.  The .exe is a portable executable file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) but this is just minimal plumbing. If you run the same .exe on Mono on a Mac this PE bootstrap code is just ignored. In both cases the real work of running the app happens within the .net framework and has nothing to do with the OS directly.

Comment: @JamesGaunt, i even build the app on Mac and then when i double clicked on the .exe it didn't work because Mac don't run .exe files. But when i run it from Xmarin IDE it ran. I don't understand which file it runs from IDE. Is it the same .exe of something else. Can you please tell. Thanks.

Comment: We seem to keep covering the same ground here! You can't run it by simply trying to launch the .exe on the Mac.  You run Mono.  Have you installed Mono?  Can you launch Mono?  If so, launch Mono and pass the path of the .exe as a parameter.  This page shows how:  http://mono-project.com/Mono:OSX

Comment: Great, glad it's sorted. Please accept the answer if that was the solution.